# setImageDrawable blurs vector drawable where as setImageResource for the same vector drawable is not

Tags: android, imageview, android-vectordrawable

When I try to set a vector drawable using setImageDrawable for image in the imageview is blurred, if use same vector drawable using setImageResource, it works perfectly. this is reproducible in Lolliop and pre-Lollipop. I dont know the reason.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in support library 26.1.0